# How to ng-translate inside select box option in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angular-translate

How do I apply ng-translate to translate options inside a select box. 
For example:

Template:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="me.gender" ng-options="gender.name for gender in genders">
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.genders = [{code: "M", name:"TXT_MALE"}, {code: "F", name:"TXT_FEMALE"}]
```

enUS.json:

```
{
    "TXT_MALE": "Male",
    "TXT_FEMALE": "Female",
}
```

I tried adding filter like `ng-options="gender.name for gender in genders | translate"`
but obviously it was adding filter to `$scope.genders` array instead of single element

I tried writing own filter (I am new to this)

```
filter('translateArrayObj', ['$translate', '_', function($translate, _) {
  return function(arr) {
    var arr2 = [];
    angular.forEach(arr, function (value, key) {
      $translate(value.name).then(function(translation) {
        var obj2 = angular.copy(value);
        obj2.name = translation;
        obj2.code = value.code;
        arr2.push(obj2);
      });
    });
    return arr2;
  }
}])
```

But I got following error

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

**It seems like a simple task but it has already taken half of my day, what am I doing wrong :(**

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to apply the filter to `gender.name` and not to the `genders` array:

```
<select ng-model="me.gender" ng-options="gender.name | translate for gender in genders"></select>
```

[Here is a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ViSF2DWK1amSW8BwwPKn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler method by using md-select, here placeholder is also used

JSON:

`"placeholder":{
 "gender": "Gender"
},
"gender": 
{
    "TXT_MALE": "Male",
    "TXT_FEMALE": "Female"
}`

HTML Code:

```
<md-select ng-model="gender" placeholder="{{'placeholder.gender' | translate}}" ng-required="true" style="width: 160px;" >
    <md-option ng-value="gender .code" ng-repeat="gender in genders" translate="gender.{{gender.name}}"></md-option>
</md-select>
```